# how to send a random message when writing a trigger word

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
# ...
else if (parts[0] == 'Zwiebelmilch') {
    const messages = [
        `for President!`,
        `an die Weltmacht!`,
        `braucht mehr Follower auf Twitter (https://twitter.com/zwiebelmilch)`,
        `ist mit Akali legendär`,
    ]
    const rndmMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.lenght)];
    message.channel.send(rndmMessage)
}
```

Comment: When next asking a question, adding essential parts of the code (for example where `parts` is defined) will help people help you with answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `length` as `lenght`.  Just fix that typo and you should be good to go!